# PHP $_POST contains raw boundary data instead of array of form fields when using FormData to upload via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, form-data

I'm using formData to post a form field with a base64 encoded string and plain text form fields via AJAX to a php page. If I omit request headers or try multipart/form-data, Firefox will not display anything in the request/response in the debugger. I'm only able to get results when using this header:

```
   xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
```

The problem is php is displaying all of the raw form fields instead of putting them in an array that I can easily access? How can I get a nice array of form fields instead the raw post?

```
var thisData = new FormData(thisForm);

xmlHttp.open("POST", thisURL+"&rndnbr="+numRand, true);
//does not work! xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8");
// removing Content-type also does not work!
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
xmlHttp.send(thisData);
```

Dumping the $_POST=

```
array (size=1)
  '-----------------------------3647481290304128341773697748

Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name' => string '"aaas_file_test"

test
-----------------------------3647481290304128341773697748
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="testfield1"

test1
-----------------------------3647481290304128341773697748
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="testfield2"

test2
-----------------------------3647481290304128341773697748
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="testfield3"

test3
-----------------------------3647481290304128341773697748
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_base64"

UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQBm4xtW2w
-----------------------------3647481290304128341773697748--
' (length=565)
```